# Add two hex numbers and store as hex number in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hex, zsh

I am trying to add two hex numbers in a shell script and store the result as a hex number.

```
let "step_size = 10"
let "start_num = 20000000"
let "size = 64"
for (( i = 0; i < 1000; i = $i + $step_size ))
do
    for (( j = 0; j < $step_size; j++ ))
    do
        let "temp = $(( $(( $i * $step_size)) + $(( $j * $size )) ))"
        num=`echo "obase=16; $temp" | bc`
        echo $num
        num2=`obase=16;ibase=16; echo $start_num \\+ $num | bc`
        echo $start_num $num $num2
        echo "****"
    done
done
```

Not all results are wrong. I get an error only when `$num = C0`

Output

```
0
20000000 0 20000000
****
40
20000000 40 20000040
****
80
20000000 80 20000080
****
C0
20000000 C0 20000090 #This is the error!!
****
100
20000000 100 20000100
****
...
...
...
1C0
20000000 1C0 20000190 #Error again!!
```

I am using zshell. I am not sure why this is happening. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your posted code doesn't produce the pasted output using `sh`, `bash`, and `zsh`.  Are you sure that you've pasted the correct code __and__ output?

Comment: There was a typo. I corrected the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably

```
num2=`obase=16;ibase=16; echo $start_num \\+ $num | bc`
```

should be

```
num2=`echo "obase=16;ibase=16;$start_num + $num" | bc`
```

You weren't calculating hex at all.

I also suggest a simpified version like this:

```
#!/bin/zsh

step_size=10
start_num=20000000
size=64

for (( i = 0; i < 1000; i += step_size )); do
    for (( j = 0; j < step_size; ++j )); do
        (( temp = (i * step_size) + (j * size) ))
        num=$(echo "obase=16; $temp" | bc)
        echo "$num"
        num2=$(echo "obase=16;ibase=16;$start_num + $num" | bc)
        echo "$start_num $num $num2"
        echo "****"
    done
done
```

And it works both in Zsh and Bash.

```
# bash temp.zsh | head -20
0
20000000 0 20000000
****
40
20000000 40 20000040
****
80
20000000 80 20000080
****
C0
20000000 C0 200000C0
****
100
20000000 100 20000100
****
140
20000000 140 20000140
****
180
20000000 180 20000180
```

Answer (score 4):

@konsolebox has a correct fix, but I think the behaviour shown in the OP is a bit mysterious, so it seems to be worth an explanation.

First, it's clear that

```
num2=`obase=16;ibase=16; echo $start_num \\+ $num | bc`
```

is incorrect because it is setting the shell variables `obase` and `ibase` rather than passing the assignment to `bc`. Also, it's unnecessary to quote the <kbd>+</kbd>. But why doesn't `bc` produce an error from the <kbd>\</kbd>, as it would if the line had been written in the modern form:

```
num2=$(obase=16;ibase=16; echo $start_num \\+ $num | bc)
```

The answer is that there is a subtle difference between `` `…` `` and `$(…)`:

```
% `echo echo \\+`
+
% $(echo echo \\+)
\+
```

Quoting the [`bash` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by <kbd>$</kbd>, <kbd>`</kbd>, or <kbd>\</kbd>. The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command substitution. When using the `$(command)` form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

In effect, that means that the backquote-version interprets the `\`-escape twice: first when the backquoted string is scanned, when `\\+` becomes `\+`, and then a second time when the resulting command is parsed, when `\+` becomes `+`.

The second question is "where did 20000090 come from?" And here the answer is that it is a curious feature of the way `bc` interprets numbers. It's worth quoting the full paragraph from `man bc` (emphasis added):

> Input numbers may contain the characters `0-9` and `A-F`. (Note: They must be capitals. Lower case letters are variable names.) Single digit numbers always have the value of the digit regardless of the value of `ibase`. (i.e. `A = 10`.)  **For multi-digit numbers, `bc` changes all input digits greater or equal to `ibase` to the value of `ibase-1`.** This makes the number `FFF` always be the largest 3 digit number of the input base.

Since `ibase` was not set in `bc` (see above), `bc` interprets `C0` as decimal `90`, although it would have interpreted `C` as decimal `12`.

---

Finally, with either `bash` or `zsh`, the following works just fine, with no need for `bc`:

```
% a=20000000
% b=C0
% printf "%X\n" $((0x$a+0x$b))
200000C0
```